# Executing a loop in React class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a pagination component and I'm struggling to execute a for loop so I can dynamically generate the pages. I initially had a function component, but I want to switch it to a class component so I can manage state in it. (I know, I can use hooks, but Im practicing class components at the moment).

I initially added the for loop in the render method but it is executing the loop twice because the component ir rendering twice. Then, I tried componentDidMount() but it doesn't do anything... then used componentWillMount() and it worked. However, I know this could be bad practice.

Any ideas? See below the component with componentDidMount()

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './Pagination.module.css';

class Pagination extends Component {
    state = {
        pageNumbers: [],
        selected: '',
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        for (
            let i = 1;
            i <= Math.ceil(this.props.totalDogs / this.props.dogsPerPage);
            i++
        ) {
            this.state.pageNumbers.push(i);
        }
    }

    classActiveForPagineHandler = (number) => {
        this.setState({ selected: number });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={styles.PaginationContainer}>
                <nav>
                    <ul className={styles.PageListHolder}>
                        {this.state.pageNumbers.map((num) => (
                            <li key={num}>
                                <a
                                    href="!#"
                                    className={
                                        this.state.selected === num
                                            ? styles.Active
                                            : styles.PageActive
                                    }
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        this.props.paginate(num);
                                        // this.props.classActiveForPagineHandler(num);
                                    }}
                                >
                                    {num}
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Pagination;
```

Comment: You're not supposed to push to a state array; you need to create the array, then call `this.setState` to update the state. `componentDidMount` is the correct place to do that (unless the props change while the comp is mounted, in which case you need `componentDidUpdate` instead) https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better push all the numbers into `array` and then update `pageNumbers` state. `this.state.pageNumbers.push(i);` does not update state directly, you need use `setState` after your calculation completes.

```
 componentDidMount() {
  const { pageNumbers = [] } = this.state
  const { totalDogs, dogsPerPage } = this.props
  for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(totalDogs / dogsPerPage); i++) {
    pageNumbers.push(i);
  }

  this.setState({ pageNumbers })
}
```

Demo link [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-react-class-dqaige?file=Pagination.js)

Comment: I tried this, but the list is not showing. if I use componentWillMount() then it works...

Comment: It's working fine for me, I created demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-react-class-dqaige?file=Pagination.js) check once. Ignored styles

Answer (score 0):

you should not update state like this :

```
this.state.pageNumbers.push(i);
```

do this:

```
  this.setState((s) => {
    return {
        ...s,
        pageNumbers: [...s.pageNumbers, i]
    }
})
```

Comment: You don't need the first `...s` in there.

Comment: Thanks, I did not realised that I didn't change the state manipulation after switching to class comp. By the way, I used shouldComponentUpdate and this stopped the second re rendering cycle from happening.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mutate `state` directly in react component. Use `setState` for all updates.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const pageNumbers = [];
  for (
    let i = 1;
    i <= Math.ceil(this.props.totalDogs / this.props.dogsPerPage);
    i++
  ) {
    pageNumbers.push(i);
  }
  this.setState({ pageNumbers });
}
```

Alternatively, you can simplify the code using `Array.from` for this case.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    pageNumbers: Array.from(
      { length: Math.ceil(this.props.totalDogs / this.props.dogsPerPage) },
      (_, i) => i + 1
    ),
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did this. but the list is not showing in the UI still? not sure why

Comment: I saw, I literally swap my code with yours and it didn't work... not sure why this could be happening. Any ideas?